# About the inner class for JAVA

Tags: java

I am learning about the **Inner Class** in Java, but i write this code, when i compile it, i got this error:
`Error:(84, 23) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

```
    public class Main {

    class Outer {
        private String string;

        Outer(String s) {
            this.string = s;
        }

        public Inner inner() {
            return new Inner();
        }

        class Inner {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return string;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer("yang");
      //  System.out.println(outer.inner().toString());
    }
}
```

I have update the Inner Class to this, and it works.

```
public class Main {

    static class Outer {
        private String string;

        Outer(String s) {
            this.string = s;
        }

        public Inner inner() {
            return new Inner();
        }

        class Inner {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return string;
            }
        }
    }
    public Outer outer(String s){
        return new Outer(s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //  Main main = new Main();
        Outer outer = new Outer("YANG");
        System.out.println(outer.inner().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(outer.inner().toString());` Are you getting the error after removing the comment from this line ??

Comment: No, The error is in `Outer outer = new Outer("yang");`

Comment: Objects that are instances of an `Outer class` exist within an instance of the Main class. so you needs to create instance of Main class to access `Outer class`.

Comment: @BhumikaThaker The only 'outer class' here is `Main`. Do you mean 'instances of the `Outer` class' and 'to access [an instance of the] `Outer` class'?

Comment: Yes I mean Outer class is equal to `Main`. as oops gives name of inner class as `Outer`.

Comment: @BlackMamba Please re-edit your question or else users might be confused with your question and you may attract down votes

Comment: @BhumikaThaker You are still perpetating the confusion between `Outer` and 'outer'. Writing 'Outer class is equal to `Main`' rather than 'outer class is equal to `Main`', and '*an* `Outer` class' rather than '*the* `Outer` class', only causes further confusion. Please be accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Despite its name, `Outer` is itself an inner class, and therefore cannot be constructed without an instance of `Main`. You need:

```
Outer outer = new Main().new Outer("yang");
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `Outer` and `Inner` are inner classes. To access them you must instantiate the main class and then you should instantiate the inner class.

So your code will be

```
Outer outer = new Main().new Outer("Yang");
```

Also [refer to this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)